# SAS Inputting Mean for Missing Questionnaire Data if Missing Less Than 80% of Values

Tags: sas, mean, missing-data, survey

I have a questionnaire coded 1-5 and then labeled as (.) for missing variables. How do I code the data to reflect the following:

If patient has =>80% values not missing than missing values will be coded as the mean value of the questions answered. If patient is missing more than 80% of values than set measure summary to missing for patient, drop record.

```
condomuse;
set int108;
run;

proc means data=condomuse n nmiss missing;
var cusesability CUSESPurchase CUSESCarry CUSESDiscuss CUSESSuggest CUSESUse CUSESMaintain CUSESEmbarrass CUSESReject CUSESUnsure CUSESConfident CUSESComfort CUSESPersuade CUSESGrace CUSESSucceed;
by Intround sid;
run;
```

Comment: Not clear what you want.  Are you trying to just force the MEAN to be missing if the variable (question) has a completion rate of less than 80%?  Or are your trying to replace the individual missing values with the mean?

Comment: Methodologically, replacing missing with the means is bad practice. Either leave as missing or use a more robust method, PROC MI in SAS covers imputation methods. You need to show the data though. Do you have a single line per individual or multiple lines? Each of those needs to be handled differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following assumptions:

- each line/record is a unique person
- all variables are numeric

NMISS(), N(), CMISS() and DIM() are functions that can work with arrays.

This will identify all records with 80% or more missing.

```
data temp; *temp is output data set name;
    set have; *have is input data set name;

    *create an array to avoid listing all variables later;
    array vars_check(*) cusesability CUSESPurchase CUSESCarry CUSESDiscuss CUSESSuggest CUSESUse CUSESMaintain CUSESEmbarrass CUSESReject CUSESUnsure CUSESConfident CUSESComfort CUSESPersuade CUSESGrace CUSESSucceed;

    *calculate percent missing;
    Percent_Missing = NMISS(of vars_check(*)) / Dim(vars_check);

    if percent_missing >= 0.8 then exclude = 'Y';
    else exclude = 'N';

 run;
```

To replace with mean or a different method, PROC STDIZE can do that.

```
*temp is input data set name from previous step;
proc stdize data=temp out=temp_mean reponly method=mean;
*keep only records with more than 80%;
where exclude = 'N';

*list of vars to fill with mean;
VAR cusesability CUSESPurchase CUSESCarry CUSESDiscuss CUSESSuggest CUSESUse CUSESMaintain CUSESEmbarrass CUSESReject CUSESUnsure CUSESConfident CUSESComfort CUSESPersuade CUSESGrace CUSESSucceed;

run;
```

The different methods for standardization are [here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_stdize_details01.htm&docsetVersion=14.3&locale=en), but these are standardization methods not imputation methods.

Comment: Thank you so much Reeza. This was incredibly helpful.